# Fire RXJS list of Observables in batches

Tags: rxjs

I have a list of observables I'd like to fire 5 at a time. I've tried using a mergeMap, but clearly I'm using it wrong:

```
// obsArray defined above... is a Array of Observables... about 30 of them

of(obsArray).pipe(
    mergeMap(x => x, 5)
).subscribe();
```

The issue is that x in the mergeMap is the entire observable list. How do I send 5 at a time to be fired (they are http calls)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from` to emit single items from an array. You can also replace `mergeMap(x => x)` with `mergeAll`.

```
from(obsArray).pipe(mergeAll(5))
```

Comment: I tacked on a "subscribe" at the end, and it doesn't appear to be firing

Comment: You know my problem was, I had a list of observable lists... Once I flattened those out, it all worked fine.